# How to change a parameter when testing widgets? Like setState

Tags: flutter, testing

I'm testing my widget, but I need to change a parameter from it, like to use the setState in the parent.

e.g:

```
bool isSelected = false;

await tester.pumpWidget(
      Testable.make(
        TagWidget(
          onPressed: (){},
          selected: isSelected,
          tag: 'tag',
        ),
      ),
    );

final textCategory = tester.widget<Text>(find.text('tag'));

expect(textCategory.data, 'tag');
expect(textCategory.style?.color, Colors.white);

isSelected = true; //I need to use something like setState here

await tester.pumpAndSettle();

expect(textCategory.style?.color, ColorsApp.preto);
```

I know that I can use tap or enterText, but I just wanna change a parameter and check if color change in an inner `Text`.

Answer (score -1):

you are just changing the value and not rendering it, for rendering there are two things:

1. Hot restart
2. Set State

   ```
   setState(() {
     isSelectted = true;
   });
   ```

Comment: Hi, it's for test my widget, the app is not running. It's for automatized tests.